How can I make one bot work constantly, and the other after 10 seconds via Python Telethon?
I have two (2) telegram, bots that should expect a new message in the chat. At the beginning, when a message appears, both bots must remember the message. Tthe first one constantly remembers the messages, the second after some time (10 seconds, for example), while the first one works constantly.
I tried to implement this method, but it doesn’t work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this code? Also, does anyone know methods of working with Teleton when the chat mode is slow?
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events, utils, functions, types
bot1 = TelegramClient()
bot2 = TelegramClient()

@bot1.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[channel_chat]))
async def handler(event):
    print("bot 1")
    

@bot2.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[channel_chat]))
async def handler(event):
    print("bot 2")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)


def main():
    bot1.start()
    bot2.start()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [
        loop.create_task(bot1.run_until_disconnected()),
        loop.create_task(bot2.run_until_disconnected())
    ]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
    loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


